Loading Lazy still loading images that are not in view
With the many images on my website, the loading times were longer than I hoped. I then came up with a solution to use lazy loading via the inline img tag loading="lazy".
<img src="images/portraits-2.jpg" alt="" loading="lazy">

Unfortunately when I look in the debug tool of the Chrome browser under the tab Network, the images are loaded all at the same time. I followed the documentation of Mozilla.
After some search on Google I came across this article. In the example they also uses the width and height attribute. This looks like it's working, but multiple images that are not in view already are loaded in the browser. In the example video on the article page, you'll see the images are loading, only when they are in view.
What am I missing?
<img src="images/portraits-2.jpg" alt="" loading="lazy" width="1080" height="1350">

